# I attended a Hackerrank online test and I got this question, I couldn't solve it, Help me out if you can

Tags: mysql, sql

[Question's Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DVIX.jpg)

I am not able to understand how to show the details for the same person for different dates, what do I group the data by for this to happen?

I have added an Image of the question do check the link out on top, it won't let me post embedded images as I am new to stackoverflow.

I have made a sample test case tables for the problem for your convinence.
Please help out if you can.

```
   Create Table delivery
(
    deliveryId int primary key,
    delivery_date date,
    De_Id int ,
    Pickup_time time ,
    delivery_time time
);

Insert Into delivery Values (450, '2020-04-17' , 111, '8:00', '9:00');
Insert Into delivery Values (451, '2020-04-17' , 111, '21:00', '23:00');
Insert Into delivery Values (452, '2020-04-17' , 111, '11:00', '11:30');
Insert Into delivery Values (453, '2020-04-17' , 112, '2:00', '3:35');
Insert Into delivery Values (454, '2020-04-17' , 112, '4:00', '4:40');
Insert Into delivery Values (455, '2020-04-17' , 112, '5:00', '7:00');
Insert Into delivery Values (456, '2020-04-18' , 111, '9:00', '11:00');
Insert Into delivery Values (457, '2020-04-18' , 111, '8:50', '9:55');
Insert Into delivery Values (458, '2020-04-18' , 111, '7:00', '9:06');
Insert Into delivery Values (459, '2020-04-18' , 112, '2:00', '3:35');
Insert Into delivery Values (460, '2020-04-18' , 112, '4:00', '4:40');
Insert Into delivery Values (461, '2020-04-18' , 112, '5:00', '7:00');

Create Table delivery_executive
(
    ID int primary key,
    Name varchar(20)
);

Insert into delivery_executive Values (111, 'Abby');
Insert into delivery_executive Values (112, 'Binto');
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text

Comment: It had the question as well as how the output should look like.
That's why I posted it and I don't understand what the harm in posting a picture with some text and the output format given in it?
Care to explain?
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to solve using MySql using `row_number` to order each delivery by the difference between the times, then filtering out all except the highest two, then using a conditional aggregate to pivot both rows with columns for each `Id`

```
with t as (
    select deliveryid, de_id, delivery_date,
        Row_Number() over(partition by delivery_date, de_id order by subtime(delivery_time,Pickup_time) desc)rn
    from delivery
)
select e.Name, t.delivery_date, 
    Max(case when rn=1 then t.deliveryid end) FirstDeliveryId, Max(case when rn=2 then t.deliveryid end) SecondDeliveryId
from t
join delivery_executive e on e.id=t.de_id
where rn<=2
group by t.delivery_date, e.Name
```

How `max` and `case` help.

It helps to work through in stages. So firstly if we start with just what the CTE (the `with t as` ) element returns for the sample data, we see 12 rows - 6 for each date - each with 3 rows per `de_id` and a row number `rn` ordered 1-3 against each group with 1 having the longest time between the pickup and delivery times and 3 the shortest.

If we just look at `select * from t where rn<=2`, that naturally removes the the rows where `rn=3` and we're left with the data we want, the two longest delivery time periods for each date, for each executive.

The desired output is to have just two rows per each executive, one for each date, and the two IDs to be in two columns.

Looking at `case` first, we can add two new columns as the result of a `case expression`,

```
case when rn=1 then t.deliveryId end,
case when rn=2 then t.deliveryId end
```

The  first `case` will have a value only where `rn=1` likewise the second `case` will have a value only where `rn=2` (by default without an `else` it returns `NULL` on all other non-matched cases).

So now we have our First and Second Id values but they are still split over two rows.

The other values on each pair of rows (rn=1 and rn=2), are the same in each case, being the same `delivery_date` and the same `de_id`, so this is now where we can `aggregate` the rows together.

The final selected columns are the `de_id` and `delivery_date` and we want to `group by` these - ie all the values that are the *same* are condensed onto a single row *provided* the columns that we do *not* `group by` are *aggregated* in some way.

The most common aggregation would be `sum`, for example if we were only selecting the *row number* column we could `sum(rn`) and the result would be 3 for each aggregated group (1+2). However using `max` it will return the maximum value for each group of rows, and since we only have either a value (`deliveryId`) or `NULL`, it returns the `deliveryId`.

Therefore we wrap each `case expression` with a `max()` function, `group by` the remaining columns and the result is the grouped columns occupy a single row in each case since the aggregate of the `case expressions` also returns 1 row.

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1c3836b12b4df897097654c9f8bc32c1)

Comment: Could you explain how `Max(case when rn=1 then t.deliveryid end) FirstDeliveryId, Max(case when rn=2 then t.deliveryid end) SecondDeliveryId` statement works?

When rn=1 it will return the max of deliveryid corresponding to it?

Comment: @TheOrgasmicThinker I've done my best to add some additional explanation above - hope it makes sense!